# How to display multiple values in angular material tool tip?

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

**how to get multiple values in an Angular Material tooltip**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="products">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Products</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let orderResult">
                    <div *ngFor="let data  of orderResult.orderDetails;let last=last" matTooltipClass="primary-tooltip" matTooltip={{data.product.productName}}>
                        {{data.product.productName}}
                        <!-- <span *ngIf="!last">,</span> -->
                    </div>
                </mat-cell>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: in a table in a column im showing tool tip on each word so i want to show a array or list of words in a material tool tip so i use truncate pipe here

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could try:

1. In your .ts file write a function that takes the array of words you want in your matToolTip as input:

```
getToolTip(arrayOfWords){
  let toolTip = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.length; i++) {
            toolTip = toolTip + ' ' + arrayOfWords[i];
        }
  return toolTip;
}
```

2. In your html add **matToolTip** as follows:

(Here "ArrayToBePassed" is the list of words you want to display in your matToolTip.)

```
<div [matTooltip]="getToolTip(ArrayToBePassed)">
```